# How do I change the default database schema in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11

By default when I create a new database in odoo, the tables are created in the public schema. Is there a way to change this configuration and that odoo create and use another defined scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, odoo use it by default and it don't provide any config for this.

And you cannot do this because a lot of the module also use sql query that retrieve the data from the public schema.

Like account, amail, sale........  etc. They assume that it's public always.